# Haskell Map on Trees with any number of branches

Tags: haskell, tree

I am trying to write a function `mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b` for a data type

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a] deriving Show
```

I know how to do this if the tree only had 2 (or any set number) possible branches, but here I am kind of stuck. So far my code looks like this:

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapTree _ Empty = Empty
mapTree f (Node a []) = Node (f a) []
mapTree f (Node a (t:ts)) = Node (f a) (mapTree f t : mapTree f ts)
```

But `mapTree f ts` is not allowed, since ts has type [Tree a]. Is there any way for me to rewrite this in a way such that I am not stuck with this error?

Comment: If only there were some sort of `mapList` that could turn your `Tree a -> Tree b` function into a `[Tree a] -> [Tree b]` function... ;-)

Comment: Notice that compiler can do this for you if you enable `DeriveFunctor` extension: `data Tree a = .... deriving (Show, Functor)`. If this is an exercise I guess you can't do that thought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider each list of length `k` as a separate case:

```
mapTree _ Empty = Empty
mapTree f (Node a []) = Node (f a) []
mapTree f (Node a [x]) = Node (f a) [mapTree f x]
mapTree f (Node a [x,y]) = Node (f a) [mapTree f x, mapTree f y]
mapTree f (Node a [x,y,z]) = Node (f a) [mapTree f x, mapTree f y, mapTree f z]
...
```

Look at the expression

```
[mapTree f x, mapTree f y, mapTree f z, ...]
```

You can simplify this using *`map`*, where the function being mapped is `mapTree f`:

```
[mapTree f x, mapTree f y, mapTree f z, ...]
    == map (mapTree f) [x, y, z, ...]
```

which lets you replace the infinite number of fixed-length cases with a single case

```
mapTree f (Node a xs) = Node (f a) (map (mapTree f) xs)
```